# Matrix properties invariant under scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, invariance

Given a square real matrix $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$, what are ALL the properties invariant under scalar multiplication?

In other words: which are the properties shared by all the $\lambda A$'s when $\lambda\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$?

The rank and the signature came to my mind. Are there some other?

Comment: I edited; I excluded $\lambda=0$. However many thanks!

Comment: Column space, row space, null space, left null space, eigen vectors, rank, to name a few.

Comment: The problem is the word *ALL*. There are arbitrary ugly properties which are invariant, e.g., that $A$ has precisely $n^2-3n+3$ zero entries, or that $A$ has exactly $n-2$ equal coefficients, or that $A$ has $3$ sign changes in the first row.